# Two way SSL handshake failed (javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException) after CertificateVerify step, while changing to the newly established cipher suite

Tags: java, security, ssl, ssl-certificate, sslhandshakeexception

I am facing an issue regarding two way SSL connection.
After enabling and going through SSL debug logs, I found that certificate-exchange happens properly.
But after CertificateVerify step, while changing to the newly established cipher suite, it is getting failed with SSLHandshakeException.

One more thing is, I am using org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory class to make connection and using javax.net.ssl.SSLContext to provide Keystore-Path, Keystore-Password, Keystore-Type and Java-truststore-path and Truststore-password.

I also installed Unlimited_JCE_Policy jar's in jre/lib/security folder.
But issue is still unresolved.

Following is the SSL debug logs(edited for sensitive info), I got after adding -Djavax.net.debug=all option in my Tomcat server.

I exhausted all my option, please help me to debug this.

```
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
%% No cached client session

*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1587274296 bytes = { 228, 35, 120, 21, 209, 132, 132, 30, 149, 198, 112, 126, 30, 140, 242, 220, 243, 241, 56, 217, 176, 72, 122, 189, 186, 84, 138, 107 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA224withDSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA
Extension server_name, server_name: [type=host_name (0), value=dummy.com]
***

*** ServerHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: -2114684890 bytes = { 90, 119, 248, 248, 216, 146, 249, 153, 116, 215, 63, 118, 5, 51, 75, 21, 65, 51, 234, 73, 65, 80, 89, 71, 5, 187, 85, 226 }
Session ID:  {112, 15, 35, 25, 164, 178, 118, 92, 24, 151, 252, 227, 204, 187, 222, 165, 37, 25, 166, 93, 48, 20, 154, 31, 32, 87, 70, 46, 28, 203, 174, 53}
Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Compression Method: 0
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
***
%% Initialized:  [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256]
** TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=dummy.com, O=DUMMY Limited, L=Mumbai, ST=Maharashtra, C=IN
  Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.111.110.1.1.11

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 4096 bits
  modulus: 7052631620228616775547420082798548950919340244279073769913613702342981771967237727631055951453640239431872969513669580187218236284810019094046772967383964532691044447883775955540400053241556727447454890970235292057633871512623754154522008251593390574617993609393573311038571044673755004608177602839240960109581315205585347515078577522273536482843663843811938218601566841063681809030993800845128902732754491954172896897202969405469795346575603858447770830369150744853454485036414564857862466788398095271768313704507089183067041424424717802090540269511201316204005685738584558793704003073277045577506581083711618971410286995431647668371083015395607216137051566569465878831815839796621268795715613323716340707965068111045737962122919999999999999933600342589999999999999845225257671111111111111111111137441
  public exponent: 64437
  Validity: [From: Mon Jul 06 12:53:18 IST 2020,
               To: Tue Oct 04 12:53:17 IST 2022]
  Issuer: CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1K, OU="(c) 2012 Entrust, Inc. - for authorized use only", OU=See www.entrust.net/legal-terms, O="Entrust, Inc.", C=US
  SerialNumber: [    05899999 86999999 41999999 a9999999]
Certificate Extensions: 10
[1]: ObjectId: 1.2.7.1.3.1.11111.1.5.1 Criticality=false

------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------
Romoved some log because it is sensitive
------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------
]
***
Found trusted certificate:
[
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=dummy.com, O=DUMMY Limited, L=Mumbai, ST=Maharashtra, C=IN
  Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 4096 bits
  modulus: 7429401386363194735786622861677554742008279854895091934024427907376991361370234298177196736239611005309266079510841102241838644451686007112674335445896622723772763105595145364023943187296951366958018721823027277873629629885038121643592346301790624375915886284810019094046772967383964532691044447883775955540400053241556727447454890970235292057633871512623754154522008251593390574617993609393573311038571044673755004608177602839240960109581315205585347515078577522273536482843663843811938218601566841063681809030993800845128902732754491954172896897202969405469795346575603858447770830369150744853454485036414564857862466788398095271768313704507089183067041424444444444444444424717802090540277777777777777777777777777714102869954316476683711111111111111111110830153956072161370511111111111111111111566569465878831815839999999999999999999997966213677137441
  public exponent: 65887
  Validity: [From: Mon Jul 06 12:53:18 IST 2020,
               To: Tue Oct 04 12:53:17 IST 2022]
  Issuer: CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1K, OU="(c) 2012 Entrust, Inc. - for authorized use only", OU=See www.entrust.net/legal-terms, O="Entrust, Inc.", C=US
  SerialNumber: [    05888888 8688888 41QAAAA a2DDDDDD]

Certificate Extensions: 10
[1]: ObjectId: 8.3.2.1.4.1.11129.2.9.2 Criticality=false
]

*** ECDH ServerKeyExchange
Signature Algorithm SHA256withRSA
Server key: Sun EC public key, 384 bits
  public x coord: 11111111111111111111117999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999
  public y coord: 22222222222222222222228888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888
------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------
Romoved some log because it is sensitive
------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------

TP-Processor3, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 36
*** CertificateRequest
Cert Types: RSA, DSS, ECDSA
Supported Signature Algorithms: SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, Unknown (hash:0x5, signature:0x2), SHA384withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, Unknown (hash:0x6, signature:0x2), SHA512withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA, SHA1withECDSA
Cert Authorities:
<Empty>

TP-Processor3, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 4
*** ServerHelloDone

*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=CLIENT.com, O=CLIENT PRIVATE LIMITED, L=Bengaluru, ST=Karnataka, C=IN
  Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.888.111111.1.1.11

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: 290917627347077908622611910632100000000000000000000000000000046087609704050900299815422531856488310792015976698480303255190950151018144486664719368897666666666666666666666666666667145802981061762927385555555555555555555555555555555555555555503641034961875452964581873004195272822222222222222222222222222222222222241568761927572710269917900733536516748436670893218496130253762999469395666158787885478532805483186099417219102169363707338972728090057330429792574728036578324737889348700154291814348847920005022222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222102150393074157132754725779611111111111111111111111111111111113565461
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Thu Dec 12 05:30:00 IST 2019,
               To: Tue Dec 15 17:30:00 IST 2020]
  Issuer: CN=DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
  SerialNumber: [    0666666a 2077777d 2888888 4199999]

Certificate Extensions: 10
[1]: ObjectId: 1.2.5.1.3.1.11155.6.7.8 Criticality=false

------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------
Romoved some log because it is sensitive
------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------
]
***
*** ECDHClientKeyExchange
ECDH Public value:  { 4, 111, 666, 74, 104, 24, 333, , 11, 121, 158, 78, 48, 248, 141, 125, 22, 85, 97, 33, 123, 231, 100 237, 255, 172, 229, 113, 51, 40, 444, 54, 66, 89, 93, 13, 999, 183, 170, 778, 889, 453, 231, 098, 123, 975 }

[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 1725
------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------
Romoved some log because it is sensitive
------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------
TP-Processor3, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 1725
[Raw write]: length = 1730
SESSION KEYGEN:
PreMaster Secret:
------------------------------------------------------------
Romoved some log because it is sensitive
------------------------------------------------------------
CONNECTION KEYGEN:
Client Nonce:
------------------------------------------------------------
Romoved some log because it is sensitive
------------------------------------------------------------
Server Nonce:
------------------------------------------------------------
Romoved some log because it is sensitive
------------------------------------------------------------
Master Secret:
------------------------------------------------------------
Romoved some log because it is sensitive
------------------------------------------------------------
... no MAC keys used for this cipher
Client write key:
0000: 11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88   99 aa BB CC BB EE FF aa   2.TY.5....N....1
Server write key:
0000: BB 79 CB 48 88 2C 99 AE   ff 14 AA DD CC 77 70 EF  .y.JU,....v.,RT.
Client write IV:
0000: B7 44 D4 EC                                        .#$.
Server write IV:
0000: EE ED BD AA                                        .22.

*** CertificateVerify
Signature Algorithm SHA256withRSA
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 264
------------------------------------------------------------
Romoved some log because it is sensitive
------------------------------------------------------------                            
TP-Processor3, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 264
[Raw write]: length = 269
------------------------------------------------------------
Romoved some log because it is sensitive
------------------------------------------------------------
TP-Processor3, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
[Raw write]: length = 6
0000: 14 03 03 00 01 01                                  ......
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 105, 155, 113, 74, 128, 211, 166, 9, 72, 46, 206, 171 }
***
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 16
0000: 22 33 44 66 88 9B BB 4A   80 DD BB 09 AA 2E NN AB  ....p.yK....M...
Padded plaintext before ENCRYPTION:  len = 16
0000: 22 33 44 66 88 9B BB 4A   80 DD BB 09 AA 2E NN AB  ....p.yK....M...
TP-Processor3, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 40
[Raw write]: length = 45
0000: 16 03 03 00 38 00 00 00   00 00 00 00 00 67 BD 19  ....(........M..
0010: 10 3B A3 99 4A 93 0F DD   53 02 12 EE 66 AA 1F 9F  .;..K...B...f...
0020: 25 43 BB 81 1B 97 BC BA   64 DD 51 53 FF           %C......d.RS.
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 15 03 03 00 02                                     .....
[Raw read]: length = 2
0000: 02 28                                              .(
TP-Processor3, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
TP-Processor3, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256]
TP-Processor3, called closeSocket()
TP-Processor3, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

Comment: My guess is that the server simply did not like the client certificate you've send. It is unclear though what the server actually expects as client certificate and how your specific certificate failed to match this expectations. Maybe look at the server side for some more useful logs?

Comment: I stuck with this same problem at least 1 month... I don't know what happen and in another app, it works...

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why it's failing, but two typical causes in this case are:

1. Your client does not provide a certificate chain up to a certificate found in the server's trust store.  Clients can and should offer intermediate certificates for client authentication.
2. The client certificate's extended key usage does not include client authentication.